# serial communication in embedded C, tcsetattr() error.

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded-linux

I am having problems with the serial communication between an embedded Linux device and a pc. Using this function:

```
short OpenPort(){
     char PortNo[100];
     unsigned int BaudRate;
     struct termios Tios;
     short ret;    
     sprintf(PortNo, "/dev/ttyS%d", 2);
     BaudRate = B9600;
     fpCom = open(PortNo, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);   
     if (fpCom < 0) {
          log_printf(LOG_ERR, " Error opening serial port: %s", strerror(errno));

          return RTN_ERR;
     } 
     Tios.c_cflag = BaudRate | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;
     Tios.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
     Tios.c_oflag = 0;
     Tios.c_lflag = 0;
     Tios.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
     Tios.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
     tcflush(fpCom, TCIFLUSH);
     ret= tcsetattr(fpCom, TCSANOW, &Tios);


     if (ret< 0) {
          log_printf(LOG_ERR, " Error setting serial configuration: %s", strerror(errno));

          return RTN_ERR;         

     }
     return RTN_OK;
}
```

I am getting the error from tcsetattr: Invalid argument

Comment: You might want to zero out the rest of the `Tios.c_cc` array?

Comment: I've always done a tcgetattr first to fill "Tios", then modified it, then written it back with tcsetattr.

Comment: I've added first to fill ret = tcgetattr(fpCom, &Tios); and still getting the same error

Comment: It could be something quirky in the driver for the serial port if you're embedded. What happens if you do a tcgetattr to fill the Tios structure then just write it straight back with tcsetattr without modifying it?

Comment: I get exactly the same, -1 invalid argument

Comment: So you can successfully get the attributes from the device with tcgetattr but cannot write the same attributes back to the device with tcsetattr? You should check the permissions on the /dev/ttyS device you're attempting to modify - your user may have read permissions but not write permissions.

Comment: Docs say TCSADRAIN  is for any change that could affect output, and you are setting baud rate, etc.  Given the output queue must still be empty, it seems a bit pedantic to reject TCSANOW, but maybe the embedded implementation is written that way.  It's an easy test, in any case.